# How to Draw multiple circle at CANVAS with mouse event

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry

I just in problem when draw multiple circle in canvas. When I draw single circle just sucessfully, but for next circle first circle is gone. Actually only one circle is exist. So, please give me something in my code for multiple circle,

this my code

```
html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>


JS
//Canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//Variables
var canvasx = $(canvas).offset().left;
var canvasy = $(canvas).offset().top;
var last_mousex = last_mousey = 0;
var mousex = mousey = 0;
var mousedown = false;

//Mousedown
$(canvas).on('mousedown', function(e) {
    last_mousex = parseInt(e.clientX-canvasx);
    last_mousey = parseInt(e.clientY-canvasy);
    mousedown = true;
});

//Mouseup
$(canvas).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    mousedown = false;
});

//Mousemove
$(canvas).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    mousex = parseInt(e.clientX-canvasx);
    mousey = parseInt(e.clientY-canvasy);
    if(mousedown) {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        //Save
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        //Dynamic scaling
        var scalex = 1*((mousex-last_mousex)/2);
        var scaley = 1*((mousey-last_mousey)/2);
        ctx.scale(scalex,scaley);
        //Create ellipse
        var centerx = (last_mousex/scalex)+1;
        var centery = (last_mousey/scaley)+1;
        ctx.arc(centerx, centery, 1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        //Restore and draw
        ctx.restore();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.stroke();
    }
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

The  `ctx.clearRect` function is clearing the canvas every time you click and move your mouse, therefore the previous circle is cleared and new circle is drew onto it. But if you remove that function, it will create a new circle every time you move the mouse and is not what you want.

My solution will be adding a array variable `circles` to store the coordinates of the circles every time you `mouseup`, and then loop through the `circles` array to draw circle after clearing the canvas.

Also, I have move out the logics to draw a circle into a function. Here is how:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//Variables
var canvasx = $(canvas).offset().left;
var canvasy = $(canvas).offset().top;
var last_mousex = 0, last_mousey = 0;
var mousex =0, mousey = 0;
var mousedown = false;
const circles = [];
//Mousedown
$(canvas).on('mousedown', function(e) {
    last_mousex = parseInt(e.clientX-canvasx);
    last_mousey = parseInt(e.clientY-canvasy);
    mousedown = true;
});

//Mouseup
$(canvas).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    mousedown = false;
    circles.push({
      x1: mousex,
      y1: mousey,
      x2: last_mousex,
      y2: last_mousey
    })
});

function drawCircle(ctx, circle) {
  const { x1,y1,x2,y2 } = circle
  ctx.beginPath();
  //Dynamic scaling
  var scalex = 1*((x1-x2)/2);
  var scaley = 1*((y1-y2)/2);
  ctx.scale(scalex,scaley);
  //Create ellipse
  var centerx = (x2/scalex)+1;
  var centery = (y2/scaley)+1;
  ctx.arc(centerx, centery, 1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  //Restore and draw
  ctx.restore();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.save();
}

//Mousemove
$(canvas).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    mousex = parseInt(e.clientX-canvasx);
    mousey = parseInt(e.clientY-canvasy);
    if(mousedown) {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        //Save
        ctx.save();
        
        circles.forEach(circle => {
          drawCircle(ctx, circle)
        })
        drawCircle(ctx, {
          x1: mousex,
          y1: mousey,
          x2: last_mousex,
          y2: last_mousey
        })
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```